# Calculate net elevation gain from a vector?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a vector data (path/route) with points equally spaced with elevation data (in the attributes table). The elevation data was extracted from a raster. I would like to calculate net elevation gain from the starting point to the ending point. Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: This does what I needed: https://github.com/havatv/qgisclimbplugin